# MYSQL position of row by order

Tags: php, mysql

I have had a look through google results, but can't find a simple answer, I have a table

id, points (and more fields, but they dont affect anything)

How would I go about Getting position of record 24(id) ordered by points DESC?

Comment: Position? Have you any field containing time of adding records?

Comment: Your question title says "by ID", your question body says "by points"... which do you want the 24th row by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to figure out out what place a user is in based on a points system?
If so then just find how many users have more points than a particular user then add 1.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 AS 'position' FROM table WHERE points > 
   ( SELECT points FROM table WHERE id = someIDhere )
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I've understood your question

```
select * from table order by points desc limit 23,1
```

Comment: how does that get the position of the row? I dont know the offset because im ordering them...

Answer (score 2):

```
Select Count(*) from (
Select ID from UnNamedTable A where A.points>(Select B.Points from UnNamedTable B where B.ID=24)
)
```

Comment: I get an error I edited it to Select Count(*) from (Select id from tv A where A.points>(Select points from tv B where B.id=24)

Comment: Thank you - writing off the top of my head without a DB handy.  Sorry about the mistake.

Comment: If it compiles try changing Select Count(*) to Select * and see what you get.  Tough to debug without a DB.  I changed Select Points to "Select B.Points", which might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a variable to keep track of your row position after sorting.  Something like this would work:

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 ‘rank’, p.* from table1 p, (SELECT @rownum:=0) ID order by Points desc limit 10;
```

Comment: That returns 10 rows? and no exact number for my specified row?